# Как заблокировать прокрутку Яндекс Карты на мобильном?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, карты

Есть карта, созданная в **Конструкторе** карт и вставленная в код страницы. При просмотре на большом экране всё хорошо и удобно, но на мобильном, при прокрутке страницы, когда доходишь до карты, она начинает двигаться вместо страницы. Вопрос такой - как отключать прокрутку **только** для мобильного?

В документации к API описано, как можно это сделать, но это не работает для карт, созданных в Конструкторе (по крайней мере мне не удалось это сделать).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как простейший костыль подойдёт любой из следующих способов:

- Накрыть её прозрачным блоком
- Выставить `pointer-events: none`

Comment: А через API к картам из Конструктора есть возможность подключиться как-нибудь? Если нет, то придётся костылями обходиться конечно

Comment: @dodbrian, понятия не имею, не работал с ними никогда.

Answer (score 0):

Можно экспортировать карту Конструктора, например, в KML или JSON и использовать через API. [Вот пример.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoxml_display) В API можно будет отключить любые [поведения](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/map-docpage/#behaviors), которые Вы считаете лишними для мобильных.

Класть слой поверх карты не стоит, так можно помешать реальной работе с картой. а если кнопки копирайтов станут некликабельными, то это еще и нарушение ПС.